# How to disable the CTRL key in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ctrl

I have written a program for work that kills windows explorer (effectively hides desktop icons, taskbar and start menu) so no users can access the internet from our machines, this works well as most machines are touch screen so no keys can be pressed and no access to OSK, but to go a step further I am needing to disable the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key when explorer is not running (Killed in my program) then enable it when they are back (Active in my program).

I've searched Google and seen a lot of ideas but none seems to work, i've got a timer that kills task manager if it starts up, the reason i need to stop <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is incase a keyboard is present on the machine i need to stop any shortcuts from being activated and they mostly seem to use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.

I know they might be other short cuts but the guys who use my machines aren't the brightest bunch of people in the world but they might be one that 'is reight good ont tinternet'.

Cheers for any advice
Mark

Comment: OSK? You mean the Task Manager? Anyway you can disable it by setting a registry key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System] DisableTaskMgr=1`

Comment: No i mean On Screen Keyboard, my machines are mostly touch screen so no keyboard is plugged in, your code is not what i was looking for, if i disable CTRL this will stop the CTRL,ALT,DEL combo or CTRL,SHIFT,ESC combo ( i hope), hope this makes sense

Comment: Yet again, disable task manager and CTRL+ALT+DEL / CTRL+SHIFT+ESC will stop working, and leave CTRL intact for other functions at the same time. Best of both worlds.

Comment: Really?? i didnt know that, so in runtime if i change the registry back will it enable taskmanager and the shortcuts?, thanks for your reply, i need the user to NOT have the ability to run explorer at all

Comment: Yes, there is even a way you can replace the original TaskMgr for some program of yours, so you can make your own Task Manager capable of killing only the processes you want the user to be able to. But you would have to Google that.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Kiosk mode.

Here is an example of enabling it in Windows 8.1:

- [Enable Kiosk Mode in Windows 8.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx)

If you are still using Windows 7, there are workarounds, like this one:

- [Creating a Kiosk Machine with Windows 7 and Two Free Applications](http://sysadministrivia.blogspot.ca/2012/05/creating-kiosk-machine-with-windows-7.html)